# .htaccess wildcard folder redirect 301 to Perl script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I currently have a site that I want to redirect "ANY/ALL" requests with with the word "booth" (non case sensitive) my link structures look like this:

- www.url.com/booth102
- www.url.com/booth103
- www.url.com/booth104

I cant seem to figure it out but here is what I have so far:

```
  //Rewrite to www
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.url.com[nc]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.url.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

  //301 Redirect Old File
  RedirectMatch 301 /booth(*) http://www.url.com/cgi-bin/test.pl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out with this:

```
# Enable Rrewrite Engine
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite SEO Friendly URL
RewriteRule ^booth.* /cgi-bin/PerlScript.pl?Target=$0 [L,NC]
```